# Algorithm for Number series row and column

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, math, numbers

I am trying to create a simple Algorithm in Dart but I think the programming language doesn't matter it is more about the Algorithm:

I am trying to make 2 lists of pairs of numbers depending on "row" and "column" for example:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 |

=> I need a Algorithm that makes me 2 lists of numbers:
first list: 2,3,6,7,10...
second list: 4,5,8,9...

But this must also work when the "columns" change like that:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

this time the first list must be:

3,4,9...

the second list:
6,7 ...

anyone has an Idea on how I could achieve this with a simple calculation? or algorithm depending on the "Maximum" amount of numbers?

Comment: It is assumed that col_1 and col_2 will always have the same length? (Same with following columns.)

Comment: Also it seems in your second case (with col_1, col_2, and col_3) that you are only accessing the outer-most columns (col_1 and col_3). Is that true or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: yes every column has the same length, the length is determined by maximum amount, for example I want 10 numbers in the first example and in the second I want 9, but should also work with 12.

Comment: Also I wold recommend removing the `flutter` and `dart` tag from the question. You've even stated that they aren't relevant. (People may down vote you)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%`

Directly, it can create a repeating series based upon the remainder of dividing by the value

For example, you could place your values into the Nth list in a list of lists (whew)

```py
>>> cols = [[],[],[]]
>>> for x in range(12):
...     cols[x % 3].append(x)
...
>>> cols
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11]]
```

```
0%5   -->  0
1%5   -->  1
...
11%5  -->  1
```

To massage values when you have (for example) some increment of 1, you can do a little math

```py
>>> for x in range(12):
...     print("x={} is in column {}".format(x + 1, (x % 3) + 1 ))
...
x=1 is in column 1
x=2 is in column 2
x=3 is in column 3
x=4 is in column 1
x=5 is in column 2
x=6 is in column 3
x=7 is in column 1
x=8 is in column 2
x=9 is in column 3
x=10 is in column 1
x=11 is in column 2
x=12 is in column 3
```

Note you may need to do some extra work to either

- know how many values you need to fill all the columns
- count and stop when you have enough rows

Examples are in Python because I'm most familiar with it
Note that work like `[[],[],[]]` should largely be avoided if a better collection is available (perhaps a `dict` of `list`s with column-name keys or [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)), but it makes for a good illustration

Comment: that is not sufficient to create those two lists

Comment: I think it is; what if you have a list of N lists and then place values in the Nth list with the mod operator?

Comment: @Momo I added an example!

Comment: you are thinking too much in columns and rows, that was just for demonstration, the idea is to turn a list of numbers: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ....
Into tow lists: 2,3,6,7,10... second list: 4,5,8,9...

Comment: @Momo you need a better example to get your point across then! In the first example `cols` is a list of lists (`[]` notation is a list). This matches up with your example tables, but then you separately want something else. Do you mean to make the two lists as columns? What happens to `1`? Does your list exist in https://oeis.org/ ?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C6%2C7%2C10%2C11%2C14%2C15%2C18%2C19&sort=&language=english&go=Search

that would be the first list

Comment: A042964? under PROG suggests the formula `a(n)=2*n+2-n%2`

Answer (score 0):

With a little discussion, https://oeis.org/A042964 seems like the solution, which suggests the following for testing entries for set membership

```
binomial(m+2, m) mod 2 = 0
```

in Python, this could be

```py
>>> from scipy.special import binom  # 3rd party math library
>>> for m in range(1, 15):
...     print("{} belongs in list {}".format(m, 1 if binom(m+2, m) % 2 == 0 else 2))
...
1 belongs in list 2
2 belongs in list 1
3 belongs in list 1
4 belongs in list 2
5 belongs in list 2
6 belongs in list 1
7 belongs in list 1
8 belongs in list 2
9 belongs in list 2
10 belongs in list 1
11 belongs in list 1
12 belongs in list 2
13 belongs in list 2
14 belongs in list 1
```

If only the first list is desired, entries can be directly generated by the formula `a(n)=2*n+2-n%2` (refer to PROG on OEIS page), rather than testing values for membership

```py
>>> a = lambda n: 2*n+2-n%2
>>> [a(n) for n in range(10)]
[2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19]
```